# Can't read from .ini file using configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini

I recently started learning python and I'm getting this issue where, using configparser to read a key from an ini file, it keep raising a key error.

I have two files:

weather.py

```py
import configparser

def get_api_key():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    return config['openweathermap']['api_key']

print(get_api_key())
```

and config.ini

```
[openweathermap]
api_key=e53647dc71abcf81c779b83f1a8807c1
```

both files are placed in the same folder.

using `print(get_api_key())` gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\weather.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(get_api_key())
  File "...\weather.py", line 6, in get_api_key
    return config['openweathermap']['api_key']
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\configparser.py", line 964, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'openweathermap'
```

Would it be possible to get some help?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
"balderman" asked me to show that both files are in the same directory,so I `cd`'d into the folder and used `ls`:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         13-Nov-21     22:31                __pycache__
-a----         13-Nov-21     23:03              0 config.ini
-a----         13-Nov-21     23:03            737 weather.py
```

Comment: Do `ls` or `dir` and show that both ini file and py script are in the same folder. Show how do you run the script from cli (from which folder)

Comment: Cannot reproduce; the code itself is fine. Double check that you are in fact reading from the file you think you are reading from.

Comment: @chepner - what do you think about `0 config.ini` (see above) ? Is that tells us the ini file is empty?

Comment: @balderman for some reason the file didn't save the data, even though I am sure I saved after writing in it.
it resolved itself but many thanks.

Comment: I don't know what `ls` you are using to produce that output, but yes, the file is empty. Your code is behaving correctly, because `config` *doesn't* have the requested key.

Comment: My config.ini has that value and a Default config and I get the same KeyError

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I changed the file path with `r"<filePath>"`

```
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read(r"..\Configurations\config.ini")
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide *absolute path* of the `.ini` file:

```
import configparser

def get_api_key():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    ini_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini')
    config.read('config.ini')
    return config['openweathermap']['api_key']

print(get_api_key())
```